# Should I always turn the same direction in Temple Run?

Tags: ios, temple-run

In Temple Run the path diverges sometimes. You either have to turn left or right. (I've never seen a choice between forward or left/right - it's either a forced direction turn, running straight ahead, or choosing between left and right.)

Should I pick a direction and always turn in it? Should I alternate between left and right? Are there any hints or signals about what kind of danger lies ahead that I can look for when deciding which way to turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually see a small bit of each left/right path as you approach a T-junction unless something like a large tree trunk is blocking your vision.

Generally I use this information to avoid gaps in the running track because I find swiping to turn and then immediately swiping to jump especially difficult during the faster parts of the game. However, if you've got faster fingers than I you may benefit from knowing the exact location of that first jump after a turn.

There's nothing special about which direction you turn, and you can make 3 turns in the same direction and not see a repeated section (however that works physically... I'm not sure). There is no benefit from always turning in one direction, you should just use the visuals you see approaching a junction to make the best decision.

Comment: The game is non-euclidean; that's how it works physically.

Comment: It was originally titled Cthulhu Runs A Marathon.

Answer (score 2):

You can look ahead at the terrain type as somewhat of a clue.  The "temple" type terrain has walls, so you can fall off by leaning. That makes it a safer choice. The "jungle" type terrain has no walls and also seems to have more opportunities to "stagger", which can cause the monkeys to catch up. Also, look for a close tree or pit immediately after the turn, which may be impossible to avoid.